# Why must I pass as reference the anonymous function in recursive anonymous functions in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, reference, aggregate-functions

Works:

```
 $t = function($x,$y) use (&$t){
...
}
```

Does not work:

```
 $t = function($x,$y) use ($t){
...
}
```

Why must I pass the function itself as reference?

Comment: How should we know? If you must do that or not depends on what `$t` is and how do you use it. You don't even show the recursion.

Comment: are *you* kidding *me*? Plainly spoken, the question is a joke: you provide NO information.

Comment: the question was about anonymous function generally; all the anonymous function need to pass themselves as reference to do recursion.

Comment: Wait.. I missed the point, you are totally right. Sorry for being rude. Give me a few minutes, I'll get a coffe and write an answer.

Comment: can cancel the vote down ? :)

Comment: [Matthew](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15063423/664108) beat me, perfect explanation. I had to edit the question to change my vote but here you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
$f = 42;
$f = function() use ($f)
{
  var_dump($f);
};
$f();
```

That outputs 42.

The `use()` is hit before the function is defined and assigned to `$f`. So if you don't pass by reference, you are accessing the variable as it was before the function was created. In this case, 42. In your case, NULL.

By passing a reference, you'll get `$f`'s value at the time the function is called, which will be the anonymous function as you are expecting (assuming you haven't reassigned $f).

Answer (score 0):

Passing Reference variable means you are accessing same variable within that scope.

Reference variable points to the same variable that were previously created.

**Example**

```
<?php

    $a = 10;

    $b = &$a;

    function change_b($pass)
    {
        $b = $pass++;
    }

    echo $b."<br />";

    change_b(&$a);

    echo $b;

?>
```

above code will output 10 and then 11.

**Recursive function has to access the same resource over and over again and that is much more efficient than copying values.**

Comment: I know, but why must I do it with anonymous functions? I do not edit it?

Comment: @Lior because recursive function has to access the same resource over and over again...this is much more efficient than copying values.

Comment: Do I need full access (pass as reference) to activate anonymous function? why?

Comment: [PHP is copy-on-write](http://www.thedeveloperday.com/php-lazy-copy/). References do not make your code more efficient or performant if you're only going to be reading the variable, not altering it.

Comment: It is not about.
my question is "Why Do I need full access on callable to activate it"?